# How to store the company name to mobile contacts using android phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, contacts

I'm having "Add Contacts" button to my page. When I pressed this button, I want to store the Firstname, Lastname, Company Name and phone number to my mobile contacts. I'm able to store the firstname,lastname and phone number. But I can't to store the company name. How could we store the company name in mobile contacts using phonegap?
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Saving the company name in a contact is really easy in PhoneGap.
You need to add an organization field to the contact object.

```
contact.organizations = [
    new ContactOrganization(true, 'work', 'Dunder Mifflin Paper Company', 'Sales Department', 'Paper Pusher')
];
```

I have listed all the properties for a ContactOrganization below.

> Properties
>
> - pref: Set to true if this ContactOrganization contains the user's
>     preferred value. (boolean)
> - type: A string that indicates what type of field this is, home for
>     example. _(DOMString)
> - name: The name of the organization. (DOMString)
> - department: The department the contract works for. (DOMString)
> - title: The contact's title at the organization. (DOMString)

More information can be found at Cordova's documentation website.
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html#ContactOrganization

For completeness I've included a full example below.

```
var contact = new Contact();
var contactName = new ContactName();
contactName.givenName = 'John';
contactName.familyName = 'Doe';
contact.name = contactName;
contact.phoneNumbers = [
    new ContactField('work', '212-555-5555', true)
];
contact.organizations = [
    new ContactOrganization(true, 'work', 'Dunder Mifflin Paper Company', 'Sales Department', 'Paper Pusher')
];
contact.save(function() {
    alert('Contact Saved!');
});
```

I tested this solution on iOS and it worked perfectly with Cordova 3.0.  It should work just the same on Android and older versions of Cordova.

Answer (score 0):

njtman's answer is right!
most of properties of contact in phonegap is:

```
{
"displayName": null,
"name": {
    "givenName": "Intellectual",
    "formatted": "Intellectual Mollusc",
    "middleName": null,
    "familyName": "Mollusc",
    "honorificPrefix": null,
    "honorificSuffix": null
},
"nickname": null,
"phoneNumbers": [{
    "type": "other",
    "value": "00353 2345235",
    "id": 0,
    "pref": false
}, {
    "type": "mobile",
    "value": " ",
    "id": 1,
    "pref": false
}],
"emails": [{
    "type": "home",
    "value": "work@intellectualmollusc.net",
    "id": 0,
    "pref": false
}],
"addresses": [{
    "postalCode": "",
    "type": "work",
    "id": 0,
    "locality": "cork",
    "pref": "false",
    "streetAddress": " ",
    "region": " ",
    "country": "Ireland"
}],
"ims": null,
"organizations": [{
    "name": "School",
    "title": "Student",
    "type": null,
    "pref": "false",
    "department": "Kitchen"
}],
"birthday": null,
"note": "YourRefUniqueID:47831",
"categories": null,
"urls": [{
    "type": "other",
    "value": "intellectualmollusc.net",
    "id": 0,
    "pref": false
}]
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Using **contacts.create** method in phonegap

```
var myContact = navigator.contacts.create({"displayName": "Test User"});
```

[API Reference](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html#contacts.create)

**Default Objects**

- Contact
- ContactName
- ContactField
- ContactAddress
- ContactOrganization
- ContactFindOptions
- ContactError

Comment: I just share the API details. You should go through the entire doc and implement.